# Codepad.org C++ code gives wrong result

Tags: c++, reference

Just a tiny question:

Can you tell me what's the issue here in [this](http://codepad.org/q40FGZBT) code ? It should print out `9` but it does `4.8921e-270`, however, when uncommenting line 4, it works just fine, too.
I don't understand what might be wrong here. Thank you !

Code:

```
double& foo() {
  double x = 9;
  double &y = x;
  //cout << y << "\n";
  return y;
}

int main() {
  cout << foo() << "\n";
}
```

Result:
`4.8921e-270`

Comment: Where do you expect the value '9' to be stored?

Comment: Make x and y static. If they are not, you have no idea what is actually coming back from foo( ).

Comment: @PeteWilson: no reason for `y` to be static here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a **bad** idea to return references/pointers to objects on the stack. They are likely destroyed when you leave the function. Try returning it as per value:

```
double foo() {
  double x = 9;
  double &y = x;
  //cout << y << "\n";
  return y;
}
```

Now the return value is *copied* instead of a reference to an object that is probably not existing anymore.

Comment: Good to know, but what if I want to avoid the return value to be copied ? I have read that the `return` statement makes a copy of an object, then assigning the return value to a variable makes a copy again. Thanks

Comment: I would not worry about that, since a `float` normally consists of 4 bytes, which do not hurt. For larger objects you could consider passing references/pointers (again, do not create them on the stack).
BTW: a pointer/reference is also 4 (or 8) bytes large. Which is also copied when you `return` it.

Comment: This was just a test for returning a reference for larger objects. Then, how can I return a reference of an object ? `void foo(double&)` is not an option since I am implementing `operator +` etc. I also want to avoid using pointers. Ty

Comment: Something like `operator+` will have to return a value, since there is nowhere sensible to store an object to return a reference to. The compiler should be able to elide the copy, and construct the returned value in place; if you're concerned about performance, you should check that that is actually happening.

Comment: @NiklasR: You have the common misconception that returning by value is expensive, when it is actually not (if you are *creating* the object inside the function, as compared to returning a reference to an object that existed before). The compiler is able to elide the copy in most cases. As a matter of fact, all calling conventions I know off treat return by value of large objects by passing a hidden pointer to the location where the object is to be created, which means that in `T value = f();`, `f` will actually construct `value` internally in place.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a reference to a local object, the object ceases to exist when `foo` completes, and then you get Undefined Behavior when you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

```
double foo() {
  double x = 9;
  double &y = x;
  //cout << y << "\n";
  return y;
}
```

Never a good idea to return references to objects on stack. Most likely they would be disappear when you leave the function.  You might try returning it as per value.

Answer (score 0):

You return a reference to a local variable - since the local variable goes out of scope as soon as foo() returns, the value no longer exists.

So you should either just change the return type to double (highly recommended) and return x or (if you absolutely want/have to return a reference) use a static variable instead:

```
double& foo() {
  static double x = 9;
  double &y = x;
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Since the guy clearly does not understand where his variables are stored, introducing static values will probably not help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I often return data members of a class by const ref:

```
class BigThing {...};

class Foo
{
public:
   const BigThing & getBT() const { return bt; } // For constant BigThing.
   BigThing & getBT() { return bt; } // For mutable BigThing.
private:
   BigThing bt;
};
```

Then as long as your instance of Foo is in scope (you don't want to return a ref to a local variable) then using one of the getBT() should be safe and efficient.